# transition-delay text opacity

Tags: html, css, delay, transition, opacity

I have a div with an image.

On hover, I want to make the image bigger and to display some text next to the div.

> I want to show the text once the first transition (make the image bigger) has ended.

I've tried a lot of things but did not manage to find any solution, here is my last try :

```css
.width-12 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.change-hover {
    width: 10%;
    transition: all 1s;
    float: left;
}

.show-hover {
    display: none;
    text-align: left;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0s;
}

.discover-no-hover:hover .change-hover {
    width: 24%;
    float: left;
}

.discover-no-hover:hover .show-hover {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    transition-delay: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="width-12 discover-no-hover">
                    <div class="box small bkg-white">
                        <div class="feature-column medium mb-50 center hover-align">
                            <div class="iconcool">
                                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/Carr%C3%A9_rouge.svg"
                                     alt="" class="img-responsive change-hover">
                            </div>
                            <div class="show-hover">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus semper varius elit, at efficitur lorem bibendum ac. Nulla feugiat, orci et laoreet vehicula, turpis ligula venenatis diam, bibendum porttitor odio leo ut enim. Aenean pretium tristique mattis. Maecenas ullamcorper iaculis ornare. Ut vitae luctus purus. Suspendisse tincidunt, lorem quis ultrices varius, turpis turpis pellentesque ante.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

[JSfiddle for those who don't like the snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/8c9gx5mu/2/)

How can I make the text appear only after the image stopped growing ? (Or after 1s, wich is the duration of the image growing)?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
.show-hover {

    display: none;
    text-align: left;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0s; /* this*/
}
```

Just amend this to

`transition: 0s opacity 1s;`

```css
.width-12 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.change-hover {
  width: 10%;
  transition: all 1s;
  float: left;
}

.show-hover {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0s opacity 1s;
}

.discover-no-hover:hover .change-hover {
  width: 24%;
  float: left;
}

.discover-no-hover:hover .show-hover {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="width-12 discover-no-hover">
  <div class="box small bkg-white">
    <div class="feature-column medium mb-50 center hover-align">
      <div class="iconcool">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/Carr%C3%A9_rouge.svg" alt="" class="img-responsive change-hover">
      </div>
      <div class="show-hover">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus semper varius elit, at efficitur lorem bibendum ac. Nulla feugiat, orci et laoreet vehicula, turpis ligula venenatis diam, bibendum porttitor odio leo ut enim. Aenean pretium tristique mattis.
        Maecenas ullamcorper iaculis ornare. Ut vitae luctus purus. Suspendisse tincidunt, lorem quis ultrices varius, turpis turpis pellentesque ante.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `visibility:0` isn't valid CSS I'm assuming you mean `visibility:hidden` but sure, if you want to.

Comment: actually you removed "display:none" on .show-hover but i need it to not take any place

Comment: something with position:absolute could do the same job but i need it to be set to relative only once the transition is done

Comment: This sounds like something you should be asking in a **new** question with much more specific details of what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Found a way to work around thank's for everything :)